# $z^5=-2$ Complex number solutions

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all complex number solutions to the equation $$z^5=-2$$

I'm a little lost in using De Moivre's theorem and Euler's formula.

Comment: I can't see how you're lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler's famous identity tells us that $e^{i(2k+1)\pi} = -1$, so $$2e^{i\pi(2k+1)} = -2 = z^5$$ Now take the fifth root of each side to solve for $z$ to get $$z = 2^{\frac{1}{5}}e^\frac{i(2k+1)\pi}{5}$$ You'll get five solutions by plugging in $k = 0,1,2,3,4$ into the complex exponent. Use the identity $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ to convert your answer back to Cartesian coordinates, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little shaky on it still. Could you show me how it would look for one k so I can be certain I'm doing this right?

Comment: I definitely can, but have you tried one yet? Try plugging in $k=0$ and playing around with the resulting exponent

Comment: I did that. I get the 2^1/5 cos(2π/5)+isin(2π/5) and from that I simply use the calculator to get the desired form. Is this right?

Comment: Oops I was too overzealous. You are almost correct, but note that $(2\cdot0 +1) \pi = \pi$, not $2\pi$, and you do need parentheses around your trig functions because the coefficient $2^\frac{1}{5}$ needs to distribute to sine and cosine

Answer (score 0):

If $z^n = a$ where $a\neq 0$ then
$$z = \sqrt[n]{|a|}e^{i\left(\frac{\arg(a)}{n}+p\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}$$
where $p\in\{0,...,n-1\}$, which gives $n$ solutions. Then use that
$$e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta+i\sin\theta $$
Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

To visualize roots on the complex Argand Diagram $ ( x + i  y)$ rotate vector  between $(0,0)$ and $(-2^{1/5},0)$ five times through an angle $ 2 \pi/5 $ around $(0,0).$